# CSS flip animation in IE: Turned side shows mirror content

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am trying to implement a flip animation from the following [website](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) and I got it to work without hover effect and with a button to toggle the transition. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43oste3q/)

A given code for IE worked good on hover, but by using the button the 2nd button is shown in the right top corner with the text mirrored. Can someone advice me how to make it show normal in the left top corner as in other browsers?This is the piece of css just for IE:

```
    /* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
    /*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container.hover .back {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .flip-container.hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

/* 
    Some vertical flip updates 
*/
.vertical.flip-container {
    position: relative;
}

    .vertical .back {
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }

    .vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
.vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
}
```

Comment: so have you solved the problem. because I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the button an absolute or fixed position in the IE portion of your css code.

Comment: I cant, according to the source website it will take away the 3d transition effect.. I also want to change the content of both sides so one button may not be in the same place as the other..